# Show an advert within loop CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

If I have the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

<li>POST</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How would I show an advert in between the posts say every 5 items or just once after 5 items?

I thought about something like `$post[5]` but not sure if I'm barking up the wrong tree. Any suggestions/feedback and examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is uniformly indexed (and if it's the result of a CakePHP `find()`, it is):

```
foreach( $posts as $index => $post ) { 

    // display the post

    if( $index % 5 == 4 ) { // every fifth post or $index == 4 for only the fifth
        // display the ad
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use === (strict comparison)

Comment: @mark Why? In what situation `$x % 5 == 4` would be different from `$x % 5 === 4`?  The index is guaranteed to be an integer if it's coming from `find()`.

Comment: just a minor clitch^^ nothing too important. but it's bad enough php isnt exactly type safe. it is considered "good" coding to work with strict types wherever possible (as in this case). @see http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/codingguidelines/php.html etc (I just linked the first documented on google, but there are probably more generic guidelines, as well).

Comment: http://developer.fellowshipone.com/patterns/code.php states a really nice sentence: "There is never a good reason to use the lesser form of comparison operators" (PS: the speed gain can be considered irrelevant by the way - although present)